# How to echo a value from this json in php

Tags: php, json

I have got the following output as json. How can i echo only DND_status from it? Following are the codes.

JSON OUTPUT:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [mobilenumber] => 9809657248 [DND_status] => on [activation_date] => 09-10-2014 17:23 [current_preference] => 0 [preference_history] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [preference_date] => 20-08-2012 [preference] => 0 [status] => Active ) [1] => Array ( [preference_date] => 13-08-2012 [preference] => 0 [status] => Active ) [2] => Array ( [preference_date] => 17-07-2012 [preference] => 0 [status] => Active ) [3] => Array ( [preference_date] => 16-07-2012 [preference] => 0 [status] => Active ) [4] => Array ( [preference_date] => 09-07-2012 [preference] => 0 [status] => Active ) ) ) )
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"X-Mashape-Key: xd7lpM6y3ImshZOdNfobRDPhiBU4p100Q2JjsnaAlOTxVWrkwZ"               
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $res = file_get_contents('https://dndcheck.p.mashape.com/index.php?mobilenos=9809657248', false, $context);
    $res = (json_decode($res, true));
    print_r ($res);          // print the above json
    echo $res['DND_status']; //not working
    echo $res->DND_status;   //not working
?>
```

Comment: `foreach($something as $something_else){...}`

Comment: That's a nested array

Comment: so how i use this to print DND_status??

Comment: like you would any other nested PHP array. follow the var_dump path down to where your data is. and in your case, it's not an object. it's an array. `$res[0]['DND_STATUS']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Directly by reading the array :**

```
<?php 

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"X-Mashape-Key: xd7lpM6y3ImshZOdNfobRDPhiBU4p100Q2JjsnaAlOTxVWrkwZ"               
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$res = file_get_contents('https://dndcheck.p.mashape.com/index.php?mobilenos=9809657248', false, $context);
$res = (json_decode($res, true));
print_r ($res);          // print the above json

echo $res[0]['DND_status']; // what you need by reading in array

?>
```

**Or with foreach loop :**

```
<?php 

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"X-Mashape-Key: xd7lpM6y3ImshZOdNfobRDPhiBU4p100Q2JjsnaAlOTxVWrkwZ"               
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$res = file_get_contents('https://dndcheck.p.mashape.com/index.php?mobilenos=9809657248', false, $context);
$res = (json_decode($res, true));
print_r ($res);          // print the above json


foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['DND_status']; // what you need by foreach method
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work :

```
echo $res[0]['DND_status'];
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comment, use foreach loop

```
foreach ($opts as $opt) {
    foreach ($opt as $op) {
        echo $op['method'];
        echo $op['header'];
    }
}
```